# Search location using UItextfield

Tags: swift, xcode

Is it possible to use Apple's search location API from a UItextfield? For example, in a form, when the user clicks the textfield, can they search for a location using Apple's API?

Comment: Like when user clicks the textField, do a location search by the text in textField?

Comment: Yes, or open another view controller with a table view, then selection the location using the api search and then place that text into the textfield

Answer (score 0):

First add a listener to your text field to catch click action

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myTargetFunction), for: .touchDown)
```

Then handle the click

```
func myTargetFunction() {
    // the string in your textField will be textField.text!
    // Now do your location search
}
```

For location search, you can use `MKLocalSearch` on a `MKMapView`. [Here](https://www.codementor.io/naturaln0va/ios-tip-apple-mapkit-mklocalsearch-du107lh8d) is a quick start guide.